# Flutter Slider Not filling till the edge of its track

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**Current code :**

```
SliderTheme(
  data: SliderThemeData(
    trackHeight: 50,
    activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
    inactiveTrackColor: Colors.white54,
    thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(
      enabledThumbRadius: 0, 
      disabledThumbRadius: 0
    ),
    thumbColor: Colors.white,
  ),
  child: Slider(
    min: 0.0,
    max: (duration!=null)
      ? duration.inMilliseconds.toDouble()
      : 0.0,
    divisions: (duration != null && !(duration.inMilliseconds==0))
      ? duration.inMilliseconds 
      : 1,// division cannot be zero, and null
    value: (this.mounted && position!=null )
      ? position.inMilliseconds.toDouble()
      : 0.0,
    onChanged: (index){
      audioPlayer.seek(Duration(
        milliseconds: index.toInt()
      )).then((x){});
    }
  ),
),
```

**Output:**

*value = min*

[image: at minimum value]

*value = max*

[image: at maximum value]

**Issues**

- At min value there is a white layer before the track.
- At max value the slider is not filling all the way to the edge.

**Desired Output**

- No white layer at min value and fill the value till the edge.

Comment: I'm afraid, this is not possible with the default flutter slider. Maybe a third party slider like [flutter_xlider](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_xlider) can do that.

Comment: I was palying around with all the options and came to the same conclusion as the user above. It doesn't seem to be possible with the `Slider` widget.

Comment: I suggest that you use a range slider instead of it.